# VSTO Outlook: new Outlook apps navigation bar overlapping custom task pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have a custom task pane that is visible in all explorer and inspector windows. Now, the new version of Outlook adds a vertical apps navigation bar in the left side, of course, you can make it not visible if you want through the advanced Outlook options, but now my issue is that the new navigation bar now is overlapping the leftmost side of the custom task pane. It looks like it is a bug from Microsoft. So how can I solve this issue? Any ideas guys?

I am having the same problem described in below link, see the screenshot in that link.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-navigation-pane-update-breaks-custom-task/c7e06be5-0fe8-4f07-84e6-1097f194640f

Comment: I'm also hitting this issue.  I upvoted the post at Microsoft and submitted my own "bug report" through the feedback form in Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known problem in Outlook, MS is aware of the issue, but there is no ETA on the fix.

I am not aware of a workaround except for padding your task pane with extra room on the left to allow for the overlap.

Comment: Do you know any links in Microsoft that talk about this officially (some official Microsoft forums, etc., just to follow it and see the progress on it)? If so, could you share and provide me it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing public, sorry. The bug report was reactivated last week.